# How do I read all but the last X bytes from a binary file?

Tags: python, file, binary, byte

I want to read all data from a binary file without the last 4 bytes. How can we do it in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read it as you normally would, then slice the result:

```
with open(path_to_file, 'rb') as f:
    f.read()[:-4]
```

Comment: Thanks man! One more question.. how to read last 4 bytes from bin file in python ?

Comment: @odiassle change `[:-4]` to `[-4:]`.

Answer (score 49):

This question is old, but for others who find this on Google, please note: doing `f.read()[:-4]` will read the whole file into memory, then slice it.

If you only need the first N bytes of a file, simply pass the size to the `read()` function as an argument:

```
with open(path_to_file, 'rb') as f:
    first_four = f.read(4)
```

This avoids reading an entire potentially large file when you could lazily read the first N bytes and stop.

If you need the last N bytes of a file, you can seek to the last block of the file with `os.lseek()`. This is more complicated and left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP wants to read the whole file except for the last 4 bytes, **not** the first 4 bytes. The title and question itself contradict, but the body of the question says `"I want to read all data from binary file without last 4 bytes"`

Comment: @DeepSpace: that's true. iirc, I put this answer here because this was the top Google result for "read first n bytes of file python" or similar, and this approach was more appropriate for my uses. I shared it in case it would help others who found this (slightly different) question looking for this particular solution. I'm still a bit new to SO though; would it have been better if I'd made a new Q and answered it myself for this purpose?